# What does reference return when object is being created in singleton pattern

Tags: java

Following is double-check implementation of singleton pattern. Thread A is executing line `test=new Test();` But just at the same time, thread B first checks the value of `test`. What's the value of `test` as for thread B?

```
class Test {
    private Test test;
    private Test() {        
    }   
    public static Test get() {
        if (test == null) {    // Thread B. When object is being created, 
                               // what's value of test. Is it always null before 
                               // Thread B new object?
            synchronized (test.getClass()) {
                if (test == null) {
                    test = new Test(); // Thread A. This thread is creating object.
                }
            }
        }
        return test;
    }
}
```

**Added**
If it's not a right version of singleton pattern, can `volatile` keyword solve the problem? That is, `private volatile Test test;`

Comment: this must be static... :  ***public Test get() {*** if not makes no sense since you will need an instance of the Test class in order to be able to call the get method

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Sorry, I modify it.

Answer (score 1):

It is unknown. That is why this implementation is considered wrong.

There is possibility that `test = new Test()` first create object then assign reference to it to `test` and only then initialize it.

So thread `B` will have reference to object, but it may be not initialized.

Comment: This link https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html explains it well.

It can be avoided using eager initialization of the resources. It's not a good approach as always but will eliminate this issue in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This one also seems to be a good approach as suggested by **Bill Pugh** to eliminate the drawbacks of **double check locking** (as mentioned in the question) and we don't need to do eager initialization as well to eliminate this :

```
public class BillPughSingleton {

   private BillPughSingleton(){}

   private static class SingletonHelper{
     private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
   }

   public static BillPughSingleton getInstance(){
    return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

Notice the `private inner static class` that contains the instance of the singleton class. When the singleton class is loaded, `SingletonHelper class` is not loaded into memory and only when someone calls the `getInstance` method, this class gets loaded and creates the Singleton class instance.

This is one of the most widely used approach for Singleton class as it doesn’t require synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

> If it's not a right version of singleton pattern, can volatile keyword
>   solve the problem?

Indeed, this :

```
private Test test;
```

should be declared :

```
private volatile Test test;
```

Otherwise the memory of the thread `B` **may** keep a stale version of `test` that **may** be `null` while the thread `A` valued it with the private constructor.

By specifying `test` as `volatile`, you ensure that any assignment on it performed by one thread will be visible by other threads.

---

Now this way of implementing a singleton is not very straight (double conditional statement plus explicit synchronization).

As two fine alternatives, you could use the enum singleton idiom :

```
public enum Test implements TestInterface{
   SINGLETON;
   ...
}
```

Note that the interface is advised to write a naturally testable implementation and to be able to switch to other implementations.

or else the Bill Pugh singleton idiom (here is in the eager flavor) :

```
public class Test{

    // executed as soon as the T class is loaded by the classLoader
    private static Test instance = new Test();

    private Test() {
    }

    public static TestgetInstance() {
      return instance;
    }
}
```